h.265 parse by python
I am interested in working in the field of compression and I am studying HEVC, I saw  file on GitHub https://gist.github.com/BrandonHaynes/17a10939ea552095cbbac4c739bf8009
but I faced several problems to use it, can I get your help? Now, after running the code,  at the code below
s.append(pack('uint:' + str(self.state['pic'].num_extra_slice_header_bits), self.slice_reserved_flag)))

I have encountered this error

ValueError: A non-zero length must be specified with a uint initializer

The file uses the bitstring module, so I converted the file from Python 2 to Python 3.
Could this be the problem?

In the repo, there is 'uint:1'  not 'uint:' , is there any typo there?
